# Magento 2.3 How to get Quote Data on product detail page

Tags: magento2, cart, quote, custom-quote

i want to get this **quote data** on product page but that not return any data ... only return below array instead of all **quote data**

**On other page it working fine issue only on product page.**

```
array(4) 
{

    ["is_checkout_cart"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["store_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["remote_ip"]=>
    string(15) "106.201.234.169"
    ["x_forwarded_for"]=>
    NULL
}
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Base\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
class Data extends AbstractHelper {
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $session;
    protected $priceHelper;
    public function __construct(Context $context,Session $session,\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
        $this->session=$session;
        $this->priceHelper=$priceHelper;
    }
    public function getCheckoutData(){
        $data_array=array();
        $checkout_data=$this->session->getQuote();
        var_dump($checkout_data->getData());exit;

    }
}
```

anyone have idea whats wrong in my code?

Comment: $this->session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()

Comment: getData nor returing anything so $this->session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() so how this return items???

Comment: print only $checkout_data or $checkout->getAllVisibleItems() and check

Comment: not working i try all ways this issue only on product page not on other page... i just want to print some data on product page.... on other page all working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
    ) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $_checkoutSession;
}

public function execute()
{
  $cartData = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
  echo count($cartData); //Return count value of quote object
}
```

**For temporary :**

Do cacheable=false in your layout file and check it.

**Still, I do not recommend to use this.**

Comment: getData nor returing anything so $this->session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() so how this return items??? please read question proper and answerer

Comment: Just for temporery, do cacheable=false in your layout block and check output.

Comment: add this into answere it working fine after set cache false

Comment: It's done......!!

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :) You can now accept answer. So, it will helpful for other also.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This :-**

**Using `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` :-**

```
protected $cart;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    ) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

public function execute()
{
    // retrieve quote items collection
    $itemsCollection = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

    // get array of all items what can be display directly
    $itemsVisible = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

    // retrieve quote items array
    $items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    foreach($items as $item) 
    {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";            
    }

}
```

Comment: this is also not working

Comment: any error in log file ??

Comment: no it just return array(4) 
{

    ["is_checkout_cart"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["store_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["remote_ip"]=>
    string(15) "106.201.234.169"
    ["x_forwarded_for"]=>
    NULL
}

Comment: i think any other issue create this probleam

Comment: issue only on product page not on other pages... same thins are working on other pages